# Problems with DOM API in LWC lightning-modal

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

I'm attempting to create a reusable [LightningModal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation) component. This modal is invoked from the JavaScript file of the user component using the .open() method. The challenge I'm facing is that I'm unable to find a way to dynamically pass HTML content to be used as the modal's body.

I've experimented with using slots, but I haven't been able to figure out how to utilize them from within the .open() method.

Another approach that I thought should work and tried was:

```
const mainNode = this.template.querySelector("[data-dinamicbody]")
const template = document.createElement('template')
template.innerHTML = this.variableThatComesFromParentAndContainsHtmlString
mainNode.appendChild(template.content)
```

However, for some reason, this approach is not functioning as expected. It functions perfectly in a standard LWC (extending LightningElement), but not within the context of the modal (which extends LightningModal). Is there a specific reason for this distinction? Or could there be an error in my implementation that I'm struggling to identify?

EDIT: The error that I'm getting is: Failed to execute "appendChild" on "Node": parameter 1 is not of type "Node". But I think that the error is misleading because template.content.nodeType exists and is type 11.

EDIT2: One major issue I encountered with slots was the difficulty in finding a way to pass the slot content through the .open() method.

Despite being able to do:

```
<c-custom-modal>
  <div slot="body">Custom html</div>
</c-custom-modal>
```

In the HTML file of the parent component, that HTML is always rendered. This rendering appears distinct from the modal that opens when I invoke customModal.open() in the JavaScript, as demonstrated in the documentation. Notably, the modal that appears through customModal.open() lacks the slot, unlike the other modal.

Comment: Using slots is the way to handle this. Could you please edit the question showing your attempt to use slots and what's issue you met?

Comment: @RubenDG Done, I've included a description of my approach. In brief, my attempt with slots involved adding the modal component tag to the parent HTML along with the necessary slots. However, this approach resulted in a couple of issues: 1. The modal was always displayed, rather than being triggered solely by the .open() method call. 2. When using the .open() method, a different modal appeared without the expected slots.